# Adding sequence of square roots

Tags: sequences-and-series, sums-of-squares

How to add sequence of square roots from square root 2 till square root 99 and how to add the sequence of their reciprocal
[here is the original problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVSz0.png)

Comment: What makes you think that this will have a nice closed form?  The result is certainly going to be irrational.

Comment: Do you want to find $S$ where $S=\frac 1{\sqrt {2}}+\frac 1{\sqrt {3}}+\frac 1{\sqrt {4}}+\ldots +\frac 1{\sqrt {97}}+\frac 1{\sqrt {98}}+\frac 1{\sqrt {99}}$?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want.

Comment: Do you also want $\sqrt {2}+\sqrt {3}+\sqrt {4}+\ldots +\sqrt {97}+\sqrt {98}+\sqrt {99}?$

Comment: You could express this as a [generalized harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers), the first as $H_{99,-\frac{1}{2}}-1$ and the second as $H_{99,\frac{1}{2}}-1$ respectively, but that is really just rewriting what you already wrote without computing anything.  If you want a computed value, you could easily get an approximation using any powerful enough calculator or computer using a simple for loop [such as wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(2)%2Bsqrt(3)%2Bsqrt(4)%2B...%2Bsqrt(99)).

Comment: $S \approx17.48960382478415342235816310930641473160012676893972993156$

Comment: Please can you have a look on the problem above.

Comment: That is a totally different problem.  The problem of finding $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4}}+\dots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{99}+\sqrt{100}}$.  This sum will telescope.

Comment: Isn't the result just 9? I'm referring to problem 30 in your slide.

Comment: Okay, how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original sums you asked for have no nice closed form and so a [calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fsqrt(2)%2B1%2Fsqrt(3)%2B1%2Fsqrt(4)%2B...%2B1%2Fsqrt(99)) is going to be the only feasible way to get a numerical result.

The sum you link to in the image is a totally different one and will have a nice result.

Notice that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1}} = \frac{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1}}{n-(n+1)}=(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n})$

You have as a result:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4}}+\dots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{99}+\sqrt{100}}$

$=(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1})+(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})+(\sqrt{4}-\sqrt{3})+\dots+(\sqrt{100}-\sqrt{99})$

$=\sqrt{100}-\sqrt{1} = 9$

Answer (score 0):

By the way if any one is looking for the sum of sequence of square roots here is the answer

http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram09.pdf